# How to run SQLite query asynchronously

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to get all the contacts from my SQLite database.

Everything is working fine, I just want to make it asynchronous and not run in the main thread, to not influence the UI.

```
public List<contacts> getAllcontacts() {
    List<contacts> contactsl = new LinkedList<contacts>();

String query = "SELECT  * FROM contacts WHERE show is not 'NOTSIGNEDUP'"
        +" ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE;";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

contacts contact = null;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        contact = new contacts();

        contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setNumero(cursor.getString(3));
        contact.setProfil(cursor.getString(2));
        contact.setShow(cursor.getString(5));
        contact.setBlocked(cursor.getString(4));
        contact.setObjectid(cursor.getString(6));
        contactsl.add(contact);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

return contactsl;
}
```

I'm calling this function from my activity :

```
  final sql s = sql.getInstance(getContext());


   if (ContactsList != null) {
       ContactsList.clear();
       ContactsList.addAll(list);
       ContactsList.addAll(s.getAllcontacts_());
       cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Is there any way to make `s.getAllcontacts()` runs asyn

I made my Fragment like this :

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<contacts>> {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ContactsAdapter cAdapter;
    private List<contacts> ContactsList;



    public ContactsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void set(List<contacts> list) {
        final sql s = sql.getInstance(getContext());


       if (ContactsList != null) {
           ContactsList.clear();
           ContactsList.addAll(list);
           ContactsList.addAll(s.getAllcontacts_());
           cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }



    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



        View view = getView();
        if(view != null) {
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_recycler);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            final sql s = sql.getInstance(view.getContext());
            ContactsList = new ArrayList<contacts>();
            cAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(ContactsList, mRecyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public android.support.v4.content.Loader<List<contacts>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new AppListLoader(this.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<List<contacts>> loader, List<contacts> data) {
        ContactsList.addAll(data);
        cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader<List<contacts>> loader) {

    }


    public static class AppListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<contacts>> {
        final sql s = sql.getInstance(getContext());
        public AppListLoader(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public List<contacts> loadInBackground() {
            return s.getAllcontacts();

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Wrap it in an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`, the same basic ways that you make anything else asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to what @CommonsWare suggests, you could also use give to the [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) a try. You could define

```
public static class AppListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Contact>> {
```

and move your querying logic in `loadInBackground()`.

Your `Activity`/`Fragment` will make then use of the `LoaderManager`. It will implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Contact>>` and `onCreateLoader` will return a new instance of your `AsyncTaskLoader`. The `List<Contact>` will be delivered as part of `onLoadFinished`

Comment: OnCreatLoader is returnin null. It has to return new `AppListLoader(getActivity());`

Comment: And how to call this function ??

Comment: Override onActivityCreated and call `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` . the method will be callee automatically by the framework

Comment: Nothing happens when calling, I updated my post wih the final Fragment code

Comment: I think that the only thing missing is the implementation of `deliverResult` in the AsyncTaskLoader